# RHSCL - php55-tidy extension not available via RHSCL

Tags: php, httpd, php5, rhel7, scl

Alright, so my high level question essentially is that the `php55` tidy extension is not available via `RHSCL`? I've already setup a new instance of `httpd24` & `php55` everything on this server is functional however one of our developers requires tidy.

I am restricted to only using EPEL & RHEL repos so I will not be able to install remi or anything else. I would like to avoid compiling from source as well. I've also looked at the `RHSCL` `rh-php56` repo and that also does not include the tidy extension?

Is tidy pre-bundled in RHSCL or php5 and I just need to enable?

**Some things I have tried:**

Extension `tidy.so` is not located in `/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules`which confirms that the module is not available.

**Installed packages**

> libtidy.x86_64 - 0.99.0-31.20091203.el7
>   libtidy-devel.x86_64 - 0.99.0-31.20091203.el7

**Installed Packages**

> php55-php.x86_64         5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-bcmath.x86_64  5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-cli.x86_64     5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-common.x86_64  5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-gd.x86_64      5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-mbstring.x86_64 5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-mysqlnd.x86_64  5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-opcache.x86_64  5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-pdo.x86_64      5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-pear.noarch     1:1.9.4-10.el7
>   php55-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64  1.3.5-1.el7
>   php55-php-process.x86_64     5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-xml.x86_64         5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-runtime.x86_64         2.0-1.el7

**Available Packages**

> php55.x86_64         2.0-1.el7
>   php55-php-dba.x86_64    5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-devel.x86_64  5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-enchant.x86_64 5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-fpm.x86_64     5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-gmp.x86_64     5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-intl.x86_64    5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-ldap.x86_64    5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-odbc.x86_64    5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64   1.3.5-1.el7
>   php55-php-pecl-memcache.x86_64      3.0.8-3.el7
>   php55-php-pecl-mongo.x86_64         1.4.5-1.el7
>   php55-php-pgsql.x86_64              5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-pspell.x86_64             5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-recode.x86_64             5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-snmp.x86_64        5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-soap.x86_64        5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-php-xmlrpc.x86_64      5.5.21-5.el7
>   php55-scldevel.x86_64        2.0-1.el7

Performing `php -m` also does not reveal tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this collection have reached its "**end of life**" in october 2016, according to [RHSCL product life cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl/), so is NOT maintained.

Second, this extension cannot be available in RHSCL, as the required library (libtidy) is not part or RHEL.

You can find additional **community** packages in [php55more](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/remi/php55more/) collection, but again this one is also EOL.

So I strongly recommend you update to a maintained collection, either **rh-php56** or **rh-php70**.

Also read [Additional PHP packages for RHSCL](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/02/23/Additional-PHP-packages-for-RHSCL) (which explain how to get tidy extension, among some others).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remi. I'd love to go with a supported PHP unfortunately it's not tested and we are in the middle of a migration. My suspensions of tidy not officially being supported was correct. I'll have to add the php55more collection to get this up and running.